# How to stop pop-up sound in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, popups

I'm working with Excel almost everyday. I have to search for data in the cells, and when that data is not present I see a pop-up message.

The pop-up come with an annoying 'ping' sound. How can I cancel the sound of the pop-ups?

Comment: This is not an Excel issue. You have to do that from Windows. `Control Panel` | `Change System Sounds` | Remove sound for `Exclamation`

Comment: @SiddharthRout Thanks a lot! You helped me

Answer (score 2):

As @Siddharth-Rout mentioned this is Windows related, so:

Go to Control Panel --> Change System Sounds --> Remove sound for Exclamation